# How to get Device Id in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub, deviceid

How can I get Device Unique Id in Android and iOS using c# in Xamarin Froms? I am using Azure Notification Hub for sending Notification. I am referring this [blog](http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=260). But in Android I am not able to find related "Settings"

Comment: What have you tried? We don't provides full solutions with trying something.

Comment: update the code you have done so far or read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use XamarinEssentials' Device Information to get device info. Later you can generate device id by combining hardware values such as manufacturer + model + total memory + device name. However, using session identifiers is recommended. You must generate session id with an expiry date. Please always be complete while asking questions. Always mention a brief scenario, what you've tried, and what you expect. Respect other developers' precious time, and provide all necessary details so that they get the gist of your scenario.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According your posted blogpost http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=260 and your short problem description I try to answer your question.

For android use
`Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);`

For iOS see your blogpost.. or optionally save the `IdentifierForVendor` e.g. in your `AppDelegate` and return this value in your `IOSDevice` class (using the name in the blogpost).
use `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.ToString()` to get the device ID on iOS.

Comment: For android, Forms.Context is obsolete , use Android.App.Application.Context istead.

Comment: If you got an error with Android.Provider user this "global::Android.Provider"

Comment: I thought it was illegal to store a users device id in ur app i may be wrong on that.

Comment: Becareful! 'UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.ToString()' just gives you new guid. When you delete your app an re-install it, The value will change. So it is not exactly device Id.

Comment: i used `Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);` on 5 application but one application return different device id but 4 other  applications return same device id, I tested all 5 application on same device

Answer (score 15):

It is detailed described [here](https://montemagno.com/unique-device-id-for-mobile-apps/). But actually you don't need to do like this and trying to get an Id from each devices. Simply creating a Guid and saving to device is also working. Xamarin has [Prefences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android) for persitent a Value in a device.

You can create a guid and save it to Prefecences as I did below:

```
var deviceId = Preferences.Get("my_deviceId", string.Empty);
if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(deviceId))
{
  deviceId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  Preferences.Set("my_deviceId", deviceId);
}
```

Benefit of this approach is you will still have same Id after you transferred your app to another device; but if you uninstall and reinstall again than you will get a new Id. For the other cases that you get an Id from device, it will be change when you transfer your app to another device.

For other cases that you want to get Id from device:

**iOS: IdentifierForDevice**

```
public string Id => UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.AsString();
```

**Android: Serial, getSerial & AndroidId**

```
    string id = string.Empty;
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
                return id;

            id = Android.OS.Build.Serial;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || id == Build.Unknown || id == "0")
            {
                try
                {
                    var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                    id = Secure.GetString(context.ContentResolver, Secure.AndroidId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Android.Util.Log.Warn("DeviceInfo", "Unable to get id: " + ex.ToString());
                }
            }

            return id;
        }
    }
```

**UWP: GetPackageSpecificToken or GetSystemIdForPublisher**

```
 string id = null;
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {

            if (id != null)
                return id;

            try
            {
                if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.System.Profile.SystemIdentification"))
                {
                    var systemId = SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForPublisher();

                    // Make sure this device can generate the IDs
                    if (systemId.Source != SystemIdentificationSource.None)
                    {
                        // The Id property has a buffer with the unique ID
                        var hardwareId = systemId.Id;
                        var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

                        var bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
                        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

                        id = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    }
                }

                if (id == null && ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification"))
                {
                    var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
                    var hardwareId = token.Id;
                    var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

                    var bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
                    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

                    id = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                }

                if (id == null)
                {
                    id = "unsupported";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                id = "unsupported";
            }

            return id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 ! And apart from the technical reasons for looking into this method, I am also going the route of app/device guids in secure storage so as to avoid any regulatory issues with pseudonymisation. A physical device id may be considered personal data.

Comment: Assuming your user has to login, you already have user-specific identification. What is the benefit of also generating a GUID? I have yet to encounter an app that didn't ask for some form of user identification (usually email).

Comment: Using a generated GUID is not an Device ID and it will be readily removed on a reset, therefore your "device id" will change. I would suggest not using this approach. I used to use IMEI but of course that is no longer available.  Look at Erdogan's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin presenting by James Montemagno.

Search it in NuGet Packages as Xam.Plugin.DeviceInf. Github link: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin

Comment: AFAIK, all features of this plugin are in Xamarin.Essentials too

Comment: @this.myself, can you share the doc link? I can't see it on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?tabs=ios