# Xamarin.Android - What is the simplest solution to uniquely identify an Android 10.0 device (API 29)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uniqueidentifier

One of our customers is updating his Android devices to version 10.0 (API 29).
The app that our customer uses is manually installed via APK on each device. Each device is NOT associated with any physical person, the devices are shared between operators.

Up to now we have always uniquely identified devices via IMEI, however with Android 10.0 (API 29) this approach is no longer available.

I've read several questions on this topic but I haven't found anywhere so far any suggestions on how to solve particular cases like this.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You could try to follow the recommendations for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232847/how-to-get-device-id-in-xamarin-forms. A simple solution would be to generate a GUID on the first app start and save it to the app's storage and then use that. The GUID only changes if the app gets uninstalled and installed again.